# Trying to access asmx web service from android,What is wrong I am doing here?

Tags: android, asp.net

What is wrong I am doing here?

I am trying to use a web service hosted on my local IIS from android device "Tablet".

1-I have successfully created and published the web service,address
       "localhost/S2/Service1.asmx". 

2- Created android application 

3-Add the KSOAP jar to the project

4-Created class called 'WebService' to handle the request and the response and to keep the handling in different thread.

WebService class:

```
   import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
   import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
   import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
   import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
   import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
   import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class WebService { 
private static String NAMESPACE ="http://tempuri.org/";
private static String URL = "http://192.168.1.7/S2/Service1.asmx";  
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";

public static String invokeHelloWorldWS(String name, String webMethName) {

String resTxt = null;

// Create request
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);

 // Property which holds input parameters
PropertyInfo sayHelloPI = new PropertyInfo();

// Set Name
 sayHelloPI.setName("Name");

// Set Value
sayHelloPI.setValue(name);

 // Set dataType
 sayHelloPI.setType(String.class);

 // Add the property to request object
request.addProperty(sayHelloPI);

// Create envelope
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
    new  SpSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

//Set envelope as dotNet
envelope.dotNet = true;

// Set output SOAP object
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
// Create HTTP call object
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

 try {
      // Invoke web service 
          androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);

       // Get the response
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

          // Assign it to resTxt variable static variable
        resTxt = response.toString();

           } catch (Exception e) {

        //Print error
        e.printStackTrace();

        //Assign error message to resTxt
    resTxt = "Error occured";                                            

    //Return resTxt to calling object                                   
    return resTxt;                              
        }

    }
         }
   }
```

Then I am have created inner class in the main activity like this:

```
                         private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

                  @Override
                  protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
                          {
                          //Invoke webservice
                          displayText = 
                          WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(editText,"SayHello");
                          return null;
                          }



                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    //Set response
                    tv.setText(displayText);
                    //Make ProgressBar invisible
                    pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }



                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    //Make ProgressBar invisible
                    pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                }


            }
```

Then I am calling this inner calls on the button on the OnClickListener like this:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
               //Check if Name text control is not empty
               if (et.getText().length() != 0 && et.getText().toString() != "") {

                  //Get the text control value
                  editText =  et.getText().toString();

                  //Create instance for AsyncCallWS
                  AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();

                   //Call execute 
                   task.execute();



               } else {
                   tv.setText("Please enter name");
               }
           }
       });
```

And of course setting all the permissions like this:

-uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 

-uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" 

-uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

After all this and following many tutorials such as
http://android.programmerguru.com/how-to-call-asp-net-web-service-in-android/#

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/

and many more other tutorials still cant work "Unfortunately, WSDemo has stopped".
If its time consuming for you to go through my code, please tell direct me to a good tutorial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post logcat output? exactly where you got the issue?

Comment: This might sound stupid (sorry if it is) - but how is your Android connecting to a resource/web service at `localhost`? - Does it actually connect to your web service? Hth....

Comment: until unless you are connected to a wifi with that localhost network you wont get this done.